# PyOpt packages not importing

Tags: python, optimization

I have decided to move from my current commercial optimization program to PyOpt.

I am having some difficulties importing certain optimizers I am struggling to find any information on PyOpt other than that on the PyOpt home site.

The optimizers not importing:

```
from pyOpt import MMFD   #Modiﬁed Method of Feasible Directions                                             
from pyOpt import MMA    #Method of Moving Asymptotes                                                                                              
from pyOpt import GCMMA  #Globally Convergent Method of Moving Asymptotes                                                                 
from pyOpt import NLPQL  #Non-Linear Programming by Quadratic Lagrangian                                                           
from pyOpt import NLPQLP #Non-Linear Programming with Non-Monotone and Distributed Search            
from pyOpt import FSQP   #Feasible Sequential Quadratic Programming
```

The rest of the optimizers import just fine. Running the help file below, the packages seem to be installed, but the specific optimizers cannot be imported.

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*

Help on package pyOpt:

NAME
    pyOpt

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpt/**init**.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS

```
pyALGENCAN (package)
pyALHSO (package)
pyALPSO (package)
pyCOBYLA (package)
pyCONMIN (package)
pyFILTERSD (package)
pyFSQP (package)
pyGCMMA (package)
pyKSOPT (package)
pyMIDACO (package)
pyMMA (package)
pyMMFD (package)
pyNLPQL (package)
pyNLPQLP (package)
pyNSGA2 (package)
pyOpt_constraint
pyOpt_gradient
pyOpt_history
pyOpt_objective
pyOpt_optimization
pyOpt_optimizer
pyOpt_parameter
pyOpt_variable
pyPSQP (package)
pySDPEN (package)
pySLSQP (package)
pySNOPT (package)
pySOLVOPT (package)
setup
```

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*

I have a suspicion that ADS (Automated Design Synthesis Optimization Program), that is  utilized in the packages, is not installed, but cant find any information on the topic (seen from the source code of the packages).

The software was also repeatedly installed on different machines with the same result, hence the suspicion of missing packages in the installer.

Any PyOpt user guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We do not use **pyOpt**, but we use **NLPQLP**, which appears on your list of packages not imported.

**[NLPQLP](http://www.ai7.uni-bayreuth.de/nlpqlp.htm)** is not for free, at least not if this is the one we use.

It could be the same for MMA which for me refers to the code produced by Svanberg at KTH.

Based on this, it could be that pyOpt only contains interfaces to those packages that are not for free.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the `LICENCE` file in the main folder:
`Some optimizers are licensed and their sources are not included with this distribution. To use them, please request their sources from the authors as indicated in the optimizer. LICENSE files, and place them in their respective source folders before installing the package.`

I had a look and this is definitely the case for MMA, GCMMA, and NLPQL. The rest I did not check. I know that one can obtain the MMA and GCMMA codes when signing an agreement with the developer.